# How to plot each team's figures throughout the years on the same line chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, linechart

My dataframe looks like this:[image]

I'm having trouble making a line chart that would take these numbers plot them throughout the different months of the year and have multiple lines on the chart for each team.

I've been trying to use pandas and seaborn but it seems like my dataframe is not in the correct format to carry out the operation I want to happen at least with my limited knowledge

Answer (score 0):

it works exactly how you would expect it to...

```py
import pandas
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

seaborn.set()

df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.uniform(1000,10000,(12,5)),columns=["A", "B", "C", "D","E"],index=range(1,13))
df.plot()

pyplot.show()
```